# Is it possible to insert 0 for boolean false and 1 for boolean true without typecasting in Postgresql 9.2

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and I want to insert 0 for Boolean false and 1 for Boolean true without using any typecasting, which is not accepting by PostgreSQL database. 
Normally PostgreSQL allow comparison of Boolean value with Integer (i.e. 0 or 1) but not insertion of Boolean value using 0 or 1 for true and false.

So is there any technique so that I can insert 0 for Boolean false and 1 for Boolean true as well as I can compare  Boolean value using 0 and 1?

this is the cast expression which I used

```
update pg_cast set castcontext = 'i' where oid in (
select c.oid
from pg_cast c
inner join pg_type src on src.oid = c.castsource
inner join pg_type tgt on tgt.oid = c.casttarget
where src.typname like 'int%' and tgt.typname like 'bool%'
)
```

Comment: Create an implicit cast from integer to boolean; see `CREATE CAST`.

Comment: @Craig thanks , i did already but when i am using implicit cast from inteager to boolean then insertion using integer 0 or 1 is working but comparison with boolean value using 0 and 1 stop working which i don't want.

Comment: *"comparison with boolean value using 0 and 1 stop working"*. Um, what? Please edit your question to show the exact `CREATE CAST` statement you ran, and sample SQL showing what you think no longer works correctly afterwards.

Comment: OK, that's half of what I suggested. Now show a statement that you think is wrong after the change but was correct before it. BTW, modifying the system catalogs directly is *highly likely to cause unexpected behaviour*. Only do this when you know *exactly* what your're doing. You should use `CREATE CAST` instead.

Comment: @Craig     "create table info(id int,is_valid Boolean);               insert into info values(1,true);insert into info values(2,0);commit; select * from info where is_valid= 1"  will not give any result, which was returning id 1 as result set before. could you please give me any cast expression which works the same as you said.

Comment: Works for me. Try doing the same steps in a new blank database. Make sure you can really reproduce the problem, then edit the question to show *all steps* required to demonstrate the problem you describe.

Comment: @Craig DataBase Name: Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.2,After creating new database and open sql editor Step 1: execute above cast expression. Step 2: execute the create, insert statement written in above comment Step 3: execute select query written in above comment. Result:ERROR:  operator is not unique: boolean = integer,SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 34